# Reverse URL problem with Django and Tastypie

Tags: django, django-piston, tastypie

We're porting our API from Django - Piston to Django-TastyPie. Everything went smoothly, 'till we got to this:

urls.py of the app

```
 url(r'^upload/', Resource(UploadHandler, authentication=KeyAuthentication()), name="api-upload"),
    url(r'^result/(?P<uuid>[^//]+)/', Resource(ResultsHandler, authentication=KeyAuthentication()), name="api-result")
```

This uses piston, so we want to change it into something for tastyPie

```
url(r'^upload/', include(upload_handler.urls), name="api-upload"),
url(r'^result/(?P<uuid>[^//]+)/', include(results_handler.urls), name="api-result")
```

But we're stuck on this fault

> Reverse for 'api-result' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'uuid': 'fbe7f421-b911-11e0-b721-001f5bf19720'}' not found.

And the Debugpage of result:

> Using the URLconf defined in MelodyService.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^melotranscript/ ^upload/
^melotranscript/ ^result/(?P[^//]+)/ ^(?Presultshandler)/$ [name='api_dispatch_list']
^melotranscript/ ^result/(?P[^//]+)/ ^(?Presultshandler)/schema/$ [name='api_get_schema']
^melotranscript/ ^result/(?P[^//]+)/ ^(?Presultshandler)/set/(?P\w[\w/;-]*)/$ [name='api_get_multiple']
^melotranscript/ ^result/(?P[^//]+)/ ^(?Presultshandler)/(?P\w[\w/-]*)/$ [name='api_dispatch_detail']
^melotranscript/ ^processed/(?P.*)$
^admin/doc/
^TOU/$ [name='TOU']
^$ [name='index']
^admin/
^doc/(?P.*)$
The current URL, melotranscript/result/fbe7f421-b911-11e0-b721-001f5bf19720/, didn't match any of these.

Someone who knows the problem? It's maybe a really silly/noobish question...

Answer (score 35):

For future visitors who are having this problem, the name of the URL is `api_dispatch_list`, and you also need to specify the API name:

```
url = reverse('api_dispatch_list', kwargs={'resource_name': 'myresource', 'api_name': 'v1'})
```

There are other URL names [that Tastypie also provides](https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L309-L312):

```
/schema/   -->  api_get_schema
/set/      -->  api_get_multiple
/$your-id/ -->  api_dispatch_detail
```

You can use those in a call to reverse, you can use them in your HTML like so:

```
{% url "api_get_schema" resource_name="myresource" api_name="v1" %}
```

Comment: is it possible to use the above in django template `{% ... %}` instead of python code?

Comment: Wow, that was difficult to figure out without this post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Django 'include' doesn't support names. Names of Tastypie urls you can find in https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py : Resource.base_urls()

Answer (score 0):

I can't write comments so I have to post here
to include it in your template you should do

```
{% url "api_dispatch_list" resource_name="app_name" api_name='v1' %}?format=json
```

or in my case it worked ONLY without the api part

```
{% url "api_dispatch_list" resource_name="app_name" %}?format=json
```

to get list of available urls of your resource, import your resource from python shell then execute the following command

```
for url in ExampleResource().urls:
    print(url.name)
```

you should get something like this

```
api_dispatch_list
api_get_schema
api_get_multiple
api_dispatch_detail
```

For more details or if you are using namespace check this
https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/409